# Avoiding printing specific page(s)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created a document for work. Due to security on the company computers the macro I have on the document is not automatically enabled.

I added directions on Page 1 for how to enable it. Now when someone prints, it prints this instruction page.

I tried to simulate a macro similar to the original one I used below, for not printing Blank Content Control, to print my instruction page as blank however, this was not effective.

```
Sub PrintReport()
Dim cc As ContentControl

For Each cc In ThisDocument.ContentControls
    If Left(cc.Range.Text, 19) = "Click here to enter" Then
        cc.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdWhite
    End If
Next

ActiveDocument.PrintOut

For Each cc In ThisDocument.ContentControls
   If Left(cc.Range.Text, 19) = "Click here to enter" Then
        cc.Range.Font.ColorIndex = 15
   End If
Next

End Sub
```

I also tried to create a macro, using assistance from this site, to only print specific pages (ie. 2-5). This did not work.

```
Sub SpecialPgOnePrint()

Application.PrintOut FileName:="Visitation Report (Fillable-Final)", _
  Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Pages:="2-5"

End Sub
```

I would appreciate help identifying a way to either A. not print page1 (preferable) or B. start printing at page2

Comment: Are you still having problem?

Comment: No! Finally. LoL. At first it did not work. . . But I retyped it & for some reason that did the trick!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
Option Explicit
Sub PagePrint()
    With ActiveDocument
        .PrintOut Range:=wdPrintFromTo, _
            From:=Format(.Sections(1).Headers(1).PageNumbers.StartingNumber + 2), _
            To:=Format(.Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber))
    End With
End Sub
```